# Is there an indexed database for ERC20 allowances?

Tags: erc-20, database, allowance

For instance, I'd like to make the following query:

> Return all the addresses that have approved spender x on a particular token

It seems that I can only query for a specific (address, spender) pair on Etherscan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you want to query this for particular token, not for all tokens.

1. Via Web3 API query Ethereum node for all `Approval` events with `_spender` equal to `x` logged by particular token contract.
2. Extract `_owner` values from all such events and deduplicate these values.  This will give you all addresses that have ever approved anything to `x`.
3. Query current allowance these addresses currently have for `x` to remove addresses that do not have allowance for `x` anymore.

Comment: Interesting. How long til I get all events? Can I use infura?

Comment: Yes, sure, infura supports such queries.  This will be indexed query, so performance should be good unless you have too many `Approval` events with `_spander` equal to `x`.